# Referencing Prometheus query in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

When using Grafana with Graphite, you can reference existing queries A and B in a third query like this:

```
sumSeries(#A,#B)
```

Using Prometheus as a data source, this doesn't even work:

```
#A
```

I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that Prometheus is the data source.

How does one reference a query in Grafana using a Prometheus data source?

Comment: It should be possible with MetaQueries plugin (https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/goshposh-metaqueries-datasource) but it doesn't work with latest version of Grafana :(. I think 6.3 is the latest supported at this very moment.